# How to map an optional collection

Tags: scala

Given

```
val optionalList: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1,2,3))
```

I currently map the elements using something like

```
optionalList.map(_.map(_ * 2))
```

I don't especially like the `map(_.map(` syntax. Is there a better approach like `optionalList.mapValues(_ * 2)` or something similar? I thought about writing an implicit object to handle this but maybe scala already has something that I don't know about

Comment: Even if you don't like `map(_.map(`, use it. It is descriptive, people understand what it means, no magic. Principle of least surprise.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments. As usual it seems there are many valid ways of dealing with this, including the original optionalList.map(_.map( ... )) syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [monad transformers](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html), e.g. scalaz `ListT`:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import ListT._

val optionalList: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1,2,3))
val doubled = listT(optionalList).map(_ * 2).run
```

but in the end, as suggested by Jean-Philippe, for a case so simple I'd stick with the classic map(_.map(, every scala programmer knows what it means at a glance

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with ...

```
implicit class OptionalSeq[I, O](input: Option[Seq[I]]) {
    def mapContents(f: (I) => O): Option[Seq[O]] = {
        input.map(_.map(f))
    }
}
...
val optionalList: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(Seq(1,2,3))
val doubled: Option[Seq[Int]] = optionalList.mapContents(_ * 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a bit more explicit then `optionalList.map(_.map(_ * 2))` this is how i would do it.

```
val doubled = optionalList match {
  case Some(list) => Some(list.map(_ * 2))
  case None       => None
}
```

The other way to 'solve' this is using an empty `List` instead of `None`. This will only work if it makes sense in your problem domain.

```
val doubled = optionalList.getOrElse(List.empty).map(_ * 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You weren't explicit about what part of `map(_.map(_ * 2))` you dislike.  If it's the visual aspect, you might consider something like `for (list <- optionalList) yield list.map(_ * 2)`

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that it was just the visual aspect as you guessed. It seems a bit like writing val a = 1 + 2 instead of val a = 3. I like your suggestion